# Can I inject shell in the below php code?

Tags: php, reverse-shell

How I can inject a shell command in the below code?

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $res = trim(shell_exec("findstr /l /m /s \"" . $_POST['search'] . "\" archive\\*"));
    if ($res) {
      echo "<center>
```

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: Seems to me that you could **pipe a command** after `finstr`, then a pound (#) to comment the rest of the line (the archive part). So the whole line remains syntactically correct and will execute normally.